# How to install gitg version 2.7 under 15.04?

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, synaptic, versions

I updated to Ubuntu 15.04. The shipped version of gitg is `3.15.1` - in Ubuntu 14.10 it was 2.7.3.

I really like to install the old version again, since the new version is very inconvenient to handle. How can I install the old version again. It is not provided in the `package force version`.

I uninstalled the new version.
I downloaded the .deb-package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/gitg/download , but when I try to install it using the double click, the new version is installed and an error it given:

```
Package operation failed

The installation or removal of a software package failed.

Selecting previously unselected package gitg.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 241499 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gitg_0.2.7-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gitg (0.2.7-3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gitg:
 libgit2-glib-1.0-0:amd64 (0.22.0-0ubuntu1) breaks gitg (<< 3.15.1) and is installed.
  Version of gitg to be configured is 0.2.7-3.

dpkg: error processing package gitg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.44.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.44.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitg
```

When I click `repair` afterwards, then the version `3.15.1` is installed. If I don't click repair, than 2.7.3 is installed (and runnable).

So, is there a better way to install an old version of gitg?

Comment: I feel your pain - I was actually looking forward to the new gitg version (since I used the old one a _lot_), but man was that a disappointment. :-/ Currently looking for alternatives...

Comment: Even today this downgrade is relevant. The changes made in newer GITG versions are disastrous. The diff pane is uncomfortable to use, and what the hell happened to the "staged" and "unstaged" inspection features ?

Answer (score 9):

Open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i gitg_0.2.7-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get remove libgit2-glib-1.0-0
```

and set on hold with:

```
sudo apt-mark hold gitg
```

The whole is reversed with

```
sudo apt-mark unhold gitg
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This package can be obtained from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/gitg/download. (If you're on a different architecture than `amd64`, select it [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gitg#pdownload).)

Comment: He already ran the `dpkg -i` command judging by his error above (or in his case, software-center doing the install).  Also, this doesn't solve the other core problem in the OP's post about resolving the dependencies.

Comment: @ThomasW. `sudo apt-get remove libgit2-glib-1.0-0` resolves the problem. Updated.

Comment: Here's the download link: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/gitg/download

Comment: @IanPhillips Thanks! Suggested an edit to this answer to include the download link.