# Marked package as 'held', but aptitude upgrades it anyway

Tags: package-management, upgrade, aptitude

I manually installed a previous version of the `gitg` application [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/615855), since I really dislike the new interface.
I then marked the package as "on hold".

After installing updates from `aptitude`, I found that the newest version was installed again. This doesn't happen when doing an `apt[-get] [dist-]upgrade`. How can I get aptitude to likewise honour the "held" status of the package?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was an issue with my workflow for installing upgrades from aptitude.

What I always did was to select the "Upgradable Packages" entry and press <kbd>+</kbd> to install. This automatically removes the "held" status for any packages, including those for which you manually installed an older version.

Instead, aptitude provides the key <kbd>U</kbd> to mark all upgradable packages to be installed, *except* those marked as "on hold", as expected. (Also available from the menu under "Actions" as "Mark Upgradable".)